# Issues with adding today extension to flutter app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, ios-extensions

I wrote an app in Flutter, and I am looking to add a native iOS today extension to it. I added the widget target but when I try to build the build fails because the app extension target can not find specific flutter libraries (which does not make sense since it wouldn't use them anyway).

From what I can gather, the xCode project is trying to include Flutter libraries with all targets?

Here is the error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nickmowen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egikkgpuyfdkbcconodjborapzme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/share'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nickmowen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egikkgpuyfdkbcconodjborapzme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nickmowen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egikkgpuyfdkbcconodjborapzme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sqflite'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nickmowen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egikkgpuyfdkbcconodjborapzme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/url_launcher'
ld: framework not found FMDB
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks!

Edit:

Going into Pods and enabling bitcode for each of the flutter libraries in there got rid of a bunch of errors, but then I am getting this error:

```
ld: '/Users/nickmowen/Library/Android/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.framework/Flutter' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/nickmowen/Library/Android/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.framework/Flutter' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: do you use them on your code , because these are not exist on the sandbox by default

Comment: I use them in the flutter code but not in the today extension. I updated with new info

Comment: According to Flutter SDK, it doesn't support bit code. You shouldn't enable it.

Comment: @SachinVas So does that mean I can't use a today extension (which I believe requires bitcode?)

Comment: Which target is giving you the FMDB error?

Comment: I guess you should make them on sandbox before you want to use it

Comment: @SachinVas it seems that sqflite is giving the FMDB error

Answer (score 5):

This works for me.

Project -> Building Settings -> Enable Bitcode  **Set to 'NO'**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2r8U.jpg)

Comment: Added new build setting for Enable Bitcode and set to No, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After `fresh` added Today Extension, **no need to enable bitcode**, just `overwrite` setting in `Target: Today Extension`:

> - `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` = "";
> - `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "";  or  `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "-ObjC";

Maybe need clear `DerivedData`